# Powershell hash tables and PSObjects - multiple values

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, multiple-values

I need help with the following for my project in SharePoint. I have an external list with values like:

```
*ToolId*                   *ProductId*

T001                       ProductA
T001                       ProductB
T002                       ProductA
T002                       ProductC
```

I use PowerShell to exort that list into a CSV. I need to manipulate the external list and my final result needs to be like that:

```
*ToolId*                 *ProductId*

T001                     ProductA; ProductB
T002                     ProductA; ProductC
```

This is my PS code so far:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

#Get the context
$ctx = Get-SPServiceContext https://path

#Get the scope
$scope = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContextScope $ctx

#Get the target site collection 
$webTarget = Get-SPWeb -identity "https://path"

#Get the Target List 
$list = $webTarget.Lists["Name of List"] 

#Array to Hold Result - PSObjects 
$ListItemCollection = @() 

#Get All List items 
$list.Items |  Where-Object { $_["ToolId"] -ne ''} | foreach { 
$ExportItem = New-Object PSObject
$ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "ToolId" -value    $_["ToolId"]
$ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "ProductId" -value $_["ProductId"]  
#Add the object with property to an Array 
$ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
} 
#Export the result Array to CSV file 
$ListItemCollection | Export-CSV "\\path\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation                        
#Dispose the web Object 
$webTarget.Dispose()
```

I'm having problems with PSObjects and hash tables to get all the items of the same `ToolId` and collect all the `ProductId`’s relevant to them to populate my CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You can group items byt `ToolId` using `Group-Object` and then build your result using `Select-Object`.
Try this one:

```
$ListItemCollection | Group-Object ToolId |
  Select @{ Label = "ToolId"; Expression = { $_.Name } }, @{ Label = "Products"; Expression = { ($_.Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProductId) } }
```

Shorter version:

```
$ListItemCollection | group ToolId | select @{ L = "ToolId"; E = { $_.Name } }, @{ L = "Products"; E = { $_.Group.ProductId } }
```

`Select-Object` cmdlet can take a collection of Label-Expression pairs instead of property names. See [Example #4](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx).

Personally I'd use hashtables instead `PSObject`.

Also it's generally bad practice to use `SPList.Items` collection. You should use `SPList.GetItems()` method instead.